# Unable to move tensor to GPU memory

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to open several image files and move them to GPU memory so that the difference between them can be computed on the GPU instead:

```py
img1 = torchvision.io.read_image(IMAGE1).float()
img1.cuda()
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: unspecified launch failure
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

If I run:

```py
img1 = torchvision.io.read_image(IMAGE1).float()
img2 = torchvision.io.read_image(IMAGE2).float()
(img2-img1).is_cuda # False
```

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Transfering tensors to a device with [`torch.Tensor.cuda`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.cuda.html) is not done inplace, it returns a copy of the original tensor. Therefore, you need:

```
img1 = img1.cuda()
img2 = img2.cuda()
```

Comment: But when I run `img1.cuda()` I keep getting the above CUDA error regardless of the assignment.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING` flag to `1`?

Comment: Fixed now. It was an issue with the driver. Thanks.